# How to set up an android device to function as a phone only

Tags: lock-screens

Is there a way to set up my android device so that when the lock screen unlocked, the phone app always is open by default? In other words: I swipe to unlock the screen and I always automatically see the phone keypad first and the device is ready to make a call.

I am trying to set up a new Samsung Galaxy Note for my grandmother BTW. Someone bought it for her for her birthday. She likes the size for her eyes, but is intimidated by the home screen, and has discarded the phone for that reason. I figure if can make it operate as she expects then she might warm up to it.

Comment: Why would you get an android phone instead of a dumb phone?

Comment: Maybe because you can't get dumb phones with text and buttons as big as the Note.

Answer (score 2):

> Install this [***Easy Phone App***](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orange.labs.easyphone&feature=also_installed#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwNCwiY29tLm9yYW5nZS5sYWJzLmVhc3lwaG9uZSJd) into your grandmother's cell and place its shortcut on the screen or the desktop of that android device.
>
> And tell her to just swipe that ***circle with lock*** off the screen (i.e Unlock  screen) whenever she sees one, and touch on that phone icon in the center! (to activate the Phone app)...

Advantages:

- Big font User Interface.
- Descriptive Graphics.

Statistics:

- Average Rating: 4.4 of 5.
- Of 153 people ***97***  have rated it **5** stars.

**Alternative-**

> Install this [***One tap dailer***](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duriapp.onetapdialer&feature=also_installed#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwNCwiY29tLmR1cmlhcHAub25ldGFwZGlhbGVyIl0.).

Features:

- It gives a *speed dail* like facility. Meaning that, it creates a dedicated app icon on screen for each and every contact. That would be good if she has some few fixed people to talk or chat to.

Statistics:

- Of 17, **7** rated it as **5** stars.

Answer (score 1):

To do exactly what you want, you can install [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en). You can try tasker from its [website](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html) rather than from Google Play store and this allows you to test it for free for 7 days in a device.

With Tasker, I created a profile which watches for an event for screen-unlock and launches dial pad once it gets triggered.  You can download the following content as an XML file and import it into your Tasker installation to test.

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="1.6u1m">
  <Profile sr="prof10" ve="2">
    <cdate>1366177538819</cdate>
    <edate>1366177654712</edate>
    <id>10</id>
    <mid0>12</mid0>
    <nme>Unlock</nme>
    <Event sr="con0" ve="2">
      <code>1000</code>
      <pri>0</pri>
    </Event>
  </Profile>
  <Task sr="task12">
    <cdate>1366177546567</cdate>
    <edate>1366177572658</edate>
    <id>12</id>
    <Action sr="act0" ve="3">
      <code>90</code>
      <Str sr="arg0" ve="3"/>
      <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
    </Action>
  </Task>
</TaskerData>
```